# python flask render_template

Tags: python, flask

Could someone explain why friend = friend is necessarily in this flask function?

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    friends = mysql.fetch("SELECT * FROM friends")
    return render_template('index.html', friends=friends)
```

Comment: When it doubt, remove it and see what happens.

Comment: Yup. Also agree with below (and above comment). If this is preexisting code that you're reading, you should be able to (if you're using Flask's default jinja templates) find a `{{ friends }}` somewhere in `index.html`. If you remove this line, take a look at what that part of the html does.

Answer (score 2):

In your template you have a variable called `friends`. This code says use the friends results in the template as `friends`.

Answer (score 1):

It's passing the friends list into the template so the data can be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is why do you have to say "friends = friends" instead of just passing "friends". Why the superfluous "friends"? The way to think about it is you are passing a keyword argument, which means defining a keyword and its value like so: "keyword = value". You might find this helpful from the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/keywordArgs.html).